# Can this jQuery dynamic DOM manipulation be done with Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

I have a page that makes AJAX requests to update content. I make the request and get JSON back that looks something like this:

```
{
    "item": {
        "id": "myElementToChange",
        "value": "My Content to update"
    }
}
```

I then parse it and update the page like this:

```
var str = '{"item": {"id": "myElementToChange","value": "<h1>My Content to update</h1>"}}';
var json = JSON.parse(str);
var $element = $("#"+json.item.id );
$element.html(json.item.value);
```

Can I do something similar in Vuejs? Or do I have to predefine a template to accommodate each type of IDs that I want to update?

http://jsfiddle.net/ogewwqzt/

Comment: The content you are going to insert is going to benefit from Vue reactivity? Or is it just static content? You can create an instance for each item, but I do not see the point if it's just plain HTML. `const createInstance = ({ id, value }) => { new Vue({ template: value }).$mount(\`#${id}\`) };` Are these dynamic components? Please elaborate.

Comment: Since this would be a retrofit, it would be static content. How would I make the static content reactive using this technique?

Answer (score 0):

I would say first that even if you use Vuejs instead of jQuery, you can still use plain js functions in your vuejs code, such as:

```
document.getElementById(json.item.id).innerHTML = json.item.value;
```

Of course it is not taking advantage of the Vuejs functionalities.

The vue way would be to use declarative rendering :

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message1 }}
  {{ message2 }}
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message1: 'yo',
    message2: 'yo2'
  }
})
```

then do your ajax call in a method, update the data (message1 and message2) with the result of your call and let vuejs reactivity features update the DOM.

Also, it seems like a very weird choice to have your server directly send an HTML id. Why would the back-end need to know the name of your html id ? You probably want to be able to change an html id without modifying the server code.

Comment: My example code is pretty simplified. This is not considered a Single Page Application. The current framework is completely server side. The server side responds with json or xml to tell client side how to format the data. Developers currently don't need to write any JavaScript. I'm trying to determine if I could enhance the current framework with Vue reactivity or if it's just too radical to provide any benefit.